# Declaring Cursor.Size

Tags: c#, windows

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Design;
using System.Drawing;

public class MouseMove
{
    public var CursorSize = Cursor.Size;
    public void MoveCursor()
    {
        Cursor.Current = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
        Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 50, Cursor.Position.Y - 50);
        Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(Cursor.Position, Cursor.Size);
    }
}
```

I'm using the following to try and move a mouse automatically, but I'm having trouble accessing the size of the mouse. It tells me that I cannot use the contextual keyword 'var' outside of a local variable declaration. Can anyone tell me how to access the size? I can't seem to get this.Cursor or this.size/position to work, so I am working around that.

Comment: google to find out what type is returned by cursor.size. OK - I'll do it for you, Its system.drawing.size

Comment: you never use the variable CursorSize anyway, just remove it

Comment: When I remove the var, it tells me that an object reference is required to access not static Size.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void MoveCursor()
{

    Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 50, Cursor.Position.Y - 50);
    Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(Cursor.Position, Cusror.Current.Size);
}
```

you have to distinguish static mehtods and proerties from non static . Look at this list https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor_properties(v=vs.110).aspx